# jQuery - Call click

Tags: jquery, plugins, lightbox

I have this jQuery which adds a click event to the selected object (from jQuery LightBox):

```
$('#jquery-overlay,#jquery-lightbox').click(function() {_finish();});
```

How in code would I call the click event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#jquery-overlay,#jquery-lightbox').click();
```

If there is no param passed it will invoke the function rather then assign it.

See the documentation at: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#jquery-overlay,#jquery-lightbox').click()
```

Or what exactly is it that you are asking?